# do i need a uk transit visa when i am not changing terminals?

Tags: london, transit-visas, lhr

I will a have a long layover of 13 hours in London Heathrow airport my ticket shows that I am arriving at terminal 2 from Cairo airport and departing from terminal 2 as well to Vancouver airport.
if i need a transit visa will i be able to leave the airport and visit London with it?

Comment: Do you want us to assume that you need a transit visa, or do you need help determining whether you need one?